# Error compiling template function in CUDA using nvcc

Tags: templates, compilation, compiler-errors, cuda, nvcc

I have the following CUDA code:

```
enum METHOD_E {
    METH_0 = 0,
    METH_1
};

template <enum METHOD_E METH>
inline __device__ int test_func<METH>()
{
    return int(METH);
}

__global__ void test_kernel()
{
    test_func<METH_0>();
}

void test()
{
    test_kernel<<<1, 1>>>();
}
```

When I compile I get the following error:

```
>nvcc --cuda test.cu
test.cu
test.cu(7): error: test_func is not a template

test.cu(14): error: identifier "test_func" is undefined

test.cu(14): error: expected an expression

3 errors detected in the compilation of "C:/Users/BLAH45~1/AppData/Local/Temp/tm
pxft_00000b60_00000000-6_test.cpp1.ii".
```

Section D.1.4 of the Programming Guide (4.0, the version of the toolkit I'm using) suggests templates should work, but I can't get them to.

Can anyone suggest a change to this code which makes it compile (without removing the templating!)?

Comment: Why does the declaration `int test_func<METH>()` include a template parameter?

Comment: Well I want to have many different methods that do different things, and to select them according to the templated type. For the timebeing there is only one simple template function, but I will augment with more complex specializations for METH_0 and METH_1, once I can get it to compile.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your `test_func` definition is wrong:

`test_func<METH>()` should be simply `test_func()`.

This works for me:

```
enum METHOD_E {
    METH_0 = 0,
    METH_1
};

template < enum METHOD_E METH>
__device__
inline
int test_func ()
{
    return int(METH);
}

__global__ void test_kernel()
{
    test_func<METH_0>();
}

void test()
{
    test_kernel<<<1, 1>>>();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Is this what you want, or did I get your problem wrong?

```
enum METHOD_E {
    METH_0 = 0,
    METH_1
};

template <enum METHOD_E METH>
inline __device__ int test_func()
{
    return int(METH);
}

template <>
inline __device__ int test_func<METH_0>()
{
    return -42;
}
```

Comment: That worked, thanks. I accepted the other answer as it was slightly more explanatory.